# Transfer data from project to widget in swift

Tags: ios, swift, widget

At my project i need to send user id's to widget in iOS. But for do that, my user needs to open application once. Without opening, information stays only 1 day, after that it vanishes and widget stops showing information and await for opening application. 
For do that i used appGroup.
What is the correct way to use transfer data from my project to widget?

[image: AppGroups]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Swift 5***

Follow these steps to pass data from the host app to extensions.

1. Select project target > Capabilities > add new app group (if you have enabled permissions for your developer account otherwise enable that first)
2. Select the extension target and repeat the same.

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.yourAppgroup") {
            createEventDic.removeAll()
            let eventDic = NSMutableDictionary()
            eventDic.setValue("YourString", forKey: "timeFontName")
            createEventDic.append(eventDic)
            
            let resultDic = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: createEventDic, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            userDefaults.set(resultDic, forKey: "setWidget")
            userDefaults.synchronize()

        } else {
        }
```

3. Now go to your app extension and do these steps to get the passed data.

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.yourAppGroup") {
            guard let testcreateEvent = userDefaults.object(forKey: "testcreateEvent") as? NSData else {
                print("Data not found in UserDefaults")
                
                return
            }
            
            do {
                guard let eventsDicArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(testcreateEvent as Data) as? [NSMutableDictionary] else {
                    fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't get Array")
                }
                
                for eventDic in eventsDicArray {
                    let timeFontName = eventDic.object(forKey: "timeFontName") as? String ?? ""
                    
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't encode data: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

Hopefully, it will help. Cheers!

Comment: You don't need `.synchronize()`. Actually, this is deprecated and the documentation advertises not using it.

Comment: Where did u get createEventDic from?

Comment: createEventDic is any dictionary you want to save & send in appgroup data. Please use yours instead.

Answer (score 1):

> For do that i used appGroup.
>
> What is the correct way to use transfer data from my project to
> widget?

What you did so far (App Grouping) is one of the steps that you should follow. Next, as mentioned in [App Extension Programming Guide - Sharing Data with Your Containing App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6):

> After you enable app groups, an app extension and its containing app
> can both use the `NSUserDefaults` API to share access to user
> preferences. To enable this sharing, use the `initWithSuiteName:` method
> to instantiate a new NSUserDefaults object, *passing in the identifier*
> *of the shared group*.

So, what you have to do so far is to let the data to be transferred by the `UserDefautls`. For instance:

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.myapp") {
    userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "myFlag")
}
```

thus you could pass it to the widget:

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.myapp") {
    let myFlag = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "myFlag")
}
```

And you follow the same approach for passing the data vise-versa (from the widget to the project).

Comment: I've used this method already, but if user doesnt open application and after 1 day passed, my data is disappears. i need to force user open application again.

Comment: @Kuroiteiken that would be related to the business of your app, *not* to how the data should be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms, we need to use DI to pass the data to the ios project then we can put it into NSUserDefaults
Info: Grouping application is mandatory

Xamarin iOS project - Putting Data into NSUserDefaults

```
 var plist = new NSUserDefaults("group.com.test.poc", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
 plist.SetBool(true, "isEnabled");
 plist.Synchronize();
```

Today Extension -  Getting data from NSUserDefaults

```
var plist = new NSUserDefaults("group.com.test.poc", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
var result = plist.BoolForKey("isEnabled");
Console.WriteLine($"The result of NSUserdefaults: logesh {result}");
```

Comment: The App Group should contain Team ID, e.g. `group.ABCD1234.com.test.poc`, where `ABCD1234` is the Team ID.