# How to use Core Bluetooth for iOS widgets?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, widgetkit

I want to show **ble service characteristic** values in iOS widget like I have successfully developed app for blood pressure to show systolic and diastolic values. Well it's must that **app is not running in background**. Only widget update by particular time and show the latest values in it. Please guide if someone have achieved  any communication for ble in  widgets. Guide how to do it? I have searched it a lot only questions found not the answers kindly share your findings. Thanks in advance. **Even if someone have done to just show Bluetooth is on or off in widget kindly share or any ble communication in widget**.

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149072/transfer-data-from-project-to-widget-in-swift may be it works for you